# Colmeans in a dataframe by factor variable

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, plyr

I'm trying to get the mean of some variables inside a dataframe for different factors. Say I have:

```
    time    geo var1    var2   var3    var4
1   1990    AT  1       7      13       19
2   1991    AT  2       8      14       20
3   1992    AT  3       9      15       21
4   1990    DE  4       10     16       22
5   1991    DE  5       11     17       23
6   1992    DE  6       12     18       24
```

And I want:

```
    time    geo var1    var2   var3    var4   m_var2   m_var3
1   1990    AT  1       7      13       19    8        14
2   1991    AT  2       8      14       20    8        14
3   1992    AT  3       9      15       21    8        14
4   1990    DE  4       10     16       22    11       17
5   1991    DE  5       11     17       23    11       17
6   1992    DE  6       12     18       24    11       17
```

I've tried a few things with by() and lapply() but I think this goes into the direction of ddply

```
require(plyr)
Dataset <- data.frame(time=rep(c(1990:1992),2),geo=c(rep("AT",3),rep("DE",3))
      ,var1=as.numeric(c(1:6)),var2=as.numeric(c(7:12)),var3=as.numeric(c(13:18)),
      var4=as.numeric(c(19:24)))

newvars <- c("var2","var3")
newData <- Dataset[,c("geo",newvars)]
```

Currently, I can choose between two errors:

```
ddply(newData,newData[,"geo"],colMeans) 
#where R apparently thinks AT is the variable?

ddply(newData,"geo",colMeans)
#where R worries about the factor variable not being numeric?
```

My lapply attempts got me quite far but then left me with a list I could not get back into the dataframe:

```
lapply(newvars,function(x){
       by(Dataset[x],Dataset[,"geo"],function(x) 
       rep(colMeans(x,na.rm=T),length(unique(Dataset[,"time"]))))
       })
```

I think this must even be able with merge and filters as here:
[Lapply in a dataframe over different variables using filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944584/lapply-in-a-dataframe-over-different-variables-using-filters/29945450#29945450) , but I can't get it together. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use `data.table`.  We can convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT(df1)`), get the `mean` (`lapply(.SD, mean)`) for the selected columns ('var2' and 'var3') by specifying the  column index in `.SDcols`, grouped by 'geo'.  Create new columns by  assigning the output (`:=`) to the new column names (`paste('m', names(df1)[4:5])`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, paste('m', names(df1)[4:5], sep="_") :=lapply(.SD, mean)
            ,by = geo, .SDcols=4:5]
#     time geo var1 var2 var3 var4 m_var2 m_var3
#1: 1990  AT    1    7   13   19      8     14
#2: 1991  AT    2    8   14   20      8     14
#3: 1992  AT    3    9   15   21      8     14
#4: 1990  DE    4   10   16   22     11     17
#5: 1991  DE    5   11   17   23     11     17
#6: 1992  DE    6   12   18   24     11     17
```

**NOTE:** This method is more general.  We can create the `mean` columns even for 100s of variables without any major change in the code.  ie. if we need to get the `mean` of columns 4:100, change the `.SDcols=4:100` and in the `paste('m', names(df1)[4:100]`.

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(time = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L
), geo = c("AT", "AT", "AT", "DE", "DE", "DE"), var1 = 1:6, var2 = 7:12, 
var3 = 13:18, var4 = 19:24), .Names = c("time", "geo", "var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Is it? okay I will then specify it

Comment: this is great, thanks! I can let it run through a vector of variables I specify myself, exactly what I need.

Comment: @Jakob I would prefer to keep the wrong code so that others understand both right and wrong.  But, you can delete it if you wish

Answer (score 7):

Other method with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(geo) %>% mutate(m_var2=mean(var2), m_var3=mean(var3))
```

Answer (score 7):

Another simple base R solution is just

```
transform(df, m_var2 = ave(var2, geo), m_var3 = ave(var3, geo))
#   time geo var1 var2 var3 var4 m_var2 m_var3
# 1 1990  AT    1    7   13   19      8     14
# 2 1991  AT    2    8   14   20      8     14
# 3 1992  AT    3    9   15   21      8     14
# 4 1990  DE    4   10   16   22     11     17
# 5 1991  DE    5   11   17   23     11     17
# 6 1992  DE    6   12   18   24     11     17
```

---

Couple years later, I think a more concise approach would be to both update the actual data set (instead of creating a new one) and operate on a vector of columns (instead of manually writing them)

```
vars <- paste0("var", 2:3) # Select desired cols
df[paste0("m_", vars)] <- lapply(df[vars], ave, df[["geo"]]) # Loop and update
```

Answer (score 4):

In `base` R:

```
 cbind(df1,m_var2=ave(df1$var2,df1$geo),m_var3=ave(df1$var3,df1$geo))
```